# Linking ImageMagick with g++ on OS 10.9.5

Tags: c++, g++, imagemagick, osx-mavericks

For a C++ project I'd like to use ImageMagick to manipulate images. To test is out, my test1.cpp is just bare-bones :

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Magick++.h>
    using namespace Magick;

    int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    return 0;}
```

And I've been trying to compile it in the terminal by using :

```
    g++ `Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags` -O2 -Wall -o test1 test1.cpp `Magick++-config --ldflags --libs`
```

and I get :

```
    fatal error: 'Magick++.h' file not found
```

I've installed the latest version of ImageMagick (convert and identify work when called from the terminal) and the first lines of my .bash_profile look like this :

```
    export MAGICK_HOME="/opt/ImageMagick-6.8.9"
    export PATH="/System/Library/Frameworks:$MAGICK_HOME/bin:$PATH"
    export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/X12/lib/pkgconfig/:$MAGICK_HOME/lib/pkgconfig"
```

All path are correct and I have already used pkg-config to successfully link a c++ program to cairo.

What am I doing wrong ? What's the simpler way to use ImageMagick in a c++ program ?
(I use vim and the terminal and do not wish to use an IDE at this point).
Thanks in advance for any help !

-- EDIT --

Here's what's returned by Magick+-config (--cxxflags and --cppflags) :

```
    -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I$MAGICK_HOME/include/ImageMagick-6
```

And by --ldflags and --libs :

```
    -L$MAGICK_HOME/lib -lMagick++-6.Q16 -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16
```

Comment: What's being returned by `Magick++-config`?

Comment: As far as the -I and -L are concerned, it looks correct. (Added it to the end of the post)

Comment: Ah, so does `echo "$MAGICK_HOME/include/ImageMagick-6"` match `echo "$(Magick++-config --prefix)/include/ImageMagick-6"` ?

Comment: Yes, matches exactly.

Comment: I get :
/opt/ImageMagick-6.8.9/include/ImageMagick-6